# Escape single quote URL query parameter in Jersey / Jackson

Tags: jackson, jersey, escaping

Long story, I need to protect some legacy code against SQL injection. Prepared statements not an option.

API are first handled by Jersey and the JSON Object deserialisation is Jackon

So, one thing I'd like is to escape all the occurrences of `'`. So when Jackson / Jersey deserialises the query parameter from the API, anytime it sees a `'` it will replace it with a `''`  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a custom string deserializer?

```
public class CustomStringDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<String> {
    protected CustomStringDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String originalValue = parser.getValueAsString();
        String escapedValue = null;
        if (originalValue != null) {
            escapedValue = originalValue.replace("'", "''");
        }
        return escapedValue;
    }
}
```